# How to run a query using variables for each row of another query

Tags: mysql

I have a table Studios where each studio can have a parentStudio.

```
+----+------+--------------+----------+
| id | name | parentStudio | criteria |
+----+------+--------------+----------+
| 0  | A    | 6            | 0        |
+----+------+--------------+----------+
| 1  | B    | 0            | 1        |
+----+------+--------------+----------+
| 2  | C    | null         | 0        |
+----+------+--------------+----------+
| 3  | D    | 2            | 1        |
+----+------+--------------+----------+
| 4  | E    | null         | 1        |
+----+------+--------------+----------+
| 5  | F    | null         | 0        |
+----+------+--------------+----------+
| 6  | G    | null         | 0        |
+----+------+--------------+----------+
```

I need to query for studios matching some criteria but also I need to get all parents of all found studios. I got a query for getting the studios that match the criteria and I also got a query for getting all parents for a known studio. I don't know how to combine them into a single query.

The query I use to get all studios that match the criteria basically looks like this:

```sql
SELECT id FROM Studios WHERE criteria = 1
+----+
| id |
+----+
| 1  |
+----+
| 3  |
+----+
| 4  |
+----+
```

The query I use for getting all parents is:

```sql
SELECT
    @currentId AS _id,
    (
        SELECT
            name
        FROM Studios
        WHERE id = _id
    ) AS name,
    (
        SELECT
            @currentId := parentStudio
        FROM Studios
        WHERE id = _id
    ) AS parentStudio,
    @level := @level + 1 AS level
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            @currentId := 1, --starting point
            @level := 0
    ) AS vars,
    Studios AS s
WHERE
    @currentId IS NOT NULL
+----+------+--------------+-------+
| id | name | parentStudio | level |
+----+------+--------------+-------+
| 1  | B    | 0            | 0     |
+----+------+--------------+-------+
| 0  | A    | 6            | 1     |
+----+------+--------------+-------+
| 6  | G    | null         | 2     |
+----+------+--------------+-------+
```

The result I'm looking for would naively look like this:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    _id AS id,
    name,
    parentStudio,
    level
FROM
    (SELECT
        @currentId AS _id,
        (
            SELECT
                name
            FROM Studios
            WHERE id = _id
        ) AS name,
        (
            SELECT
                @currentId := parentStudio
            FROM Studios
            WHERE id = _id
        ) AS parentStudio,
        @level := @level + 1 AS level
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                @currentId := (SELECT id FROM Studios WHERE criteria = 1),
                @level := 0
        ) AS vars,
        Studios AS s
    WHERE
        @currentId IS NOT NULL
)
```

But obviously this won't work because `(SELECT id FROM Studios WHERE criteria = 1)` provides more than one result.

The wanted result set would look like this:

```
+----+------+--------------+-------+
| id | name | parentStudio | level |
+----+------+--------------+-------+
| 1  | B    | 0            | 0     |
+----+------+--------------+-------+
| 0  | A    | null         | 1     |
+----+------+--------------+-------+
| 6  | G    | null         | 2     |
+----+------+--------------+-------+
| 3  | D    | 2            | 0     |
+----+------+--------------+-------+
| 2  | C    | null         | 1     |
+----+------+--------------+-------+
| 4  | E    | null         | 0     |
+----+------+--------------+-------+
```

Notice that id 5 (name F) is not in the result set.
It doesn't match the criteria itself and it isn't an ancestor of any studio that does match the criteria.

Is there any way this could be done in only SQL (MySQL 5)?

Comment: i think your real question is [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query) as it seams you are trying to query a parent child relation (a.k.a The Adjacency List Model)..

Comment: if not see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Hi and thank you for the linked answer but I already have a recursive query that gives me the parents. I added some example data and I hope that makes it easier to understand what I need.